# How can I find all the elements with border [border-radius] etc applied?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I can query for elements for example that have a title property like;

```
$$('*[title]')
```

Lets say I want to find all elements with border / or border-radius applied, I tried some queries but they did not work.

```
$$('*[border-width]')
// returns nothing
$$('*[border-width="1px"]')
// returns nothings
```

this are applied on class level but I tried a few with inline styling, still does not work.

So how can you find elements with lets say, some specific border, padding, etc applied?

Comment: That would only find them if the element had that attribute, as in `<div border-width="1px">`. This is different than what you probably intended to search for: `<div style="border-width: 1px;">`. You could probably get away with `$$('[style*=border]')`.

Comment: If you know that the styling is applied inline through a style="..." you could find them (with the 'get away with' caveat) as in @Ouroborous comment, but if they are picking styles up from classes I think you'd have to invoke some Javascript to plod through everything looking at computed style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working Demo:** https://dojo.telerik.com/IlOVEsAS/7

```js
function getElementByCSSProps(props){
    var elements = $("*").filter(function(e){
       var borderWidth = parseInt($(this).css(props));
       return borderWidth > 0;
    });
  return elements;
}
```

**The above function will return elements based on the passed parameter.**

For e.g 
`getElementByCSSProps("border-width");` - This line will return all elements with border.

`getElementByCSSProps("border-radius");` - This line will return all elements with border-radius.